# protect routes in NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Well, I'm starting with nuxt, I have the routes:

```
/home

/dashboard

/login
```

I am wanting to protect the `/dashboard` only for users logged in with token in LocalStorage

the simplest way I thought of doing this was by creating a `/middleware/auth.js`

```
export default function () {
  if (!window.localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    window.location = '/login'
  }
}
```

and registering it in the `/dashboard/index.vue` component

```
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
}
</script>
```

But this way it does not work, I can not get localstorage in the middleware

```
window is not defined
```

someone to help?

Note: I will not use Vuex in this project.

Comment: I think using cookies would be a lot more straight forward because cookies will be sent to server in each request while local storage is only accessible in client-side and you can not access it directly from server using middleware. For cookies you can use this module : https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module it also comes with examples and uses js-cookie and cookie packages.

Comment: it did not help, I said I'm not using vuex, everything in that documentation uses vuex and does not talk about cookie-js at all, and I can not access document.cookie in middleware as well.

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/ Try this

Comment: And import what library?

Comment: `if (process.browser) {
  if (!window.localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    window.location = '/login'
  }
}`

Comment: @dziraf not working. nothing happens, nor returns error.

Comment: @YungSilva document.cookie is client side, you need cookies in server so it is obvious that it will not work. Get the context `export default function (context) {}` and use `context.req.headers['cookie']`

Comment: @r3zaxd1
I'm almost there, how do I read a specific cookie?

Comment: Use this module : https://github.com/jshttp/cookie and then cookie.parse(context.req.headers[“cookie”])

Comment: I built a starter template a while back which includes JWT, express middleware https://github.com/lcherone/starter-template

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, too. Might I suggest using cookies over localStorage?

Nuxt, being the SSR wrapper that it is, looks first to the server for it's data, then the client. As the commenters have already resolved for you, `middleware` will check the server implementation first IF AND ONLY IF it's trying to be rendered on the first page load (including a manual browser refresh and anchor links not associated to the Nuxt/Vue router instance). LocalStorage is only available to the browser so any attempts to access it MUST be on the client. If you store your token data as a cookie, the Nuxt server will be able to access it as, by HTTP request protocol, your cookies are sent on every page request.

Taking advantage of the Nuxt `store` is the first step to a cookie-base resolution by using the `actions` hook `nuxtServerInit` (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action). This will give you the first chance to apply server-side states for your store (the access token state, specifically) that Nuxt will automatically pre-set for the client-side store.

I use the `universal-cookies` package but it's simple enough to create your own conditional method for detecting and parsing server received or client stored cookies.

`store/index.js`

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookies'

export const state = () = ({
  token: null
})

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    const cookies = new Cookies(req.headers.cookie)
    const token = cookies.get('token')
    commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_TOKEN: (state, token) => {
    state.token = token
  }
}

export const getters = {
  token: state => state.token
}
```

Now your middleware will have access to the store's state of the token regardless of whether it is being read from the server or client. This is possible by the Nuxt `context` object always being provided as the first argument to the middleware methods. `context` also contains a handy, universal `redirect` method of which you will need to take advantage.

`middleware/auth.js`

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.getters['token']) {
    redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

This technically does not resolve your issue with making it work with localStorage but I'm hopeful you and anyone else will find, given Nuxt's server-side-first approach, cookies are a friendlier solution for handling authorization/authentication requests.

Comment: This problem with this is now you have to protect your app with CSRF antiforgery tokens on every post request with cookies. That's one of the main advantages of using JWT's and localstorage. Looks like we've come full circle...

Answer (score 0):

Let's check this out - https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware/

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
    // If the user is not authenticated
    if (!store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

Simple and efficient =)